# Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I have a doubt regarding the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem.

The version that I know is the following from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem),
requiring, in particular, $\{f_k(x)\}$ monotone increasing and $f_k(x)\geq 0$ $\forall k, x$.

> Do you know other versions of the theorem? For example, do you know a version of the theorem (i) requiring $\{f_k(x\})$ monotone decreasing and (ii) allowing for $f_k(x)$ positive and negative across $k,x$?

I'm asking this because I don't understand which monotone convergence theorem  is applied in van der Vaart "Asymptotic Theory" proof of Theorem 5.14.

Comment: The theorem for $f_n\ge0$ and increasing obviously implies a similar result for $f_n\le0$ and decreasing. (Let $g_n=-f_n$, apply the standard MCT to $g_n$...)

Comment: yes, but what if $f_n$ positive and negative?

Comment: What does $\geq\leq$ mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f_k(x)$ not necessarily all positive across $k,x$ or all negative across $k,x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f_n$ is monotone decreasing, then $g_n=f_1-f_n$ is monotone increasing and always positive, regardless of the sign of $f_n$ (note that monotonicity allows one change of sign, anyway). So you can apply standard MCT to prove that $g_n \to f_1-f$.

Comment: But then the theorem applies to $g_n$ or $f_n$?

Comment: @STF Apply MCT to $g_n$.

Comment: do we need $\int f_n d \mu <\infty$ $\forall n$?

Comment: Where is that required in the Wikipedia page?

Comment: It is not, but it seems required in  van der Vaart "Asymptotic Theory" proof of Theorem 5.14.

Comment: I don't know that book, maybe it is required for other reasons, I can't know. My answer gives you a trick to apply MCT when it is not immediate you can, I hope that helps.